# Intersection of uncountable family of $\sigma$-algebras

Tags: measure-theory

> Suppose that $\{F_\alpha\}$ is an uncountable family of $\sigma$-algebras, and let $H=\bigcap_\alpha F_\alpha$. Is $H$ also a $\sigma$-algebra? Why or why not?

I understand that the intersection of two $\sigma$-algebras is still a $\sigma$-algebra, but what is special about the "uncountable family"? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What did you try? Repeat the argument that you use for only two.

Comment: Not that there's only one size of "uncountable" ;) Try a more general statement: remove the word "uncountable". Suppose $(F_{\alpha})$ is a nonempty family of $\sigma$-algebras, of any size, on the same underlying set (of course - this is important!); is $\bigcap_{\alpha} F_{\alpha}$ a $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: The INTERSECTION of any nonempty family of $\sigma$-algebras (on the same underlying set) is a $\sigma$-algebra.  The proof "comes" directly from the definitions.